# Custom Post Type with Sequence ID

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, categories, id

I am looking for a way in WordPress custom post type (portfolio) to manage the content of each category with a specific ID sequence.

With the "Custom Post Type Permalinks" plugin, I can manage the permalinks, and I can use the ID. But I need the sequence number for the portfolio.

/design-idea/ is a category
Sequence Number is each posted item

https://example.com/portfolio/design-idea/001/

https://example.com/portfolio/design-idea/002/

https://example.com/portfolio/design-idea/003/

https://example.com/portfolio/design-idea/004/

https://example.com/portfolio/design-idea/005/

.
.
.

https://example.com/portfolio/design-idea/265/

https://example.com/portfolio/design-idea/266/

and other categories... with own IDs -  or any other solutions without category, just sequences in IDs.

I appreciate your advice,

Thanks.

Comment: You can't have 2 posts with the same slug, even if they have different categories, they need to be unique. This is unavoidable.

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks,  According to the whole of the database structure yes, but what happens if I create a new table and use the table row ID (not post_ id: https://i.postimg.cc/xjzQT6cC/image.png)?

Comment: You would need to build out a replacement for posts, custom rewrite rules, custom templates, raw SQL queries, you'd lose all the REST APIs, post editing, no `WP_Query`/`get_posts`, no plugin support, no taxonomies/categories, it would be a massive piece of work, I estimate it would take a developer at the WP Core developer level several weeks of full-time work to build properly